# Linear Programming problem - Proportion

Tags: linear-programming

A farmer can purchase 3 kinds of feed for his stock, with various percentages of each of 4 nutrients, called A, B, C, and D.  A mixture of feeds gives proportional amounts of nutrients.  The following table gives the minimum daily requirements (lb), cost (¢ / lb), and nutritional elements per pound of feed.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPCf4.png)

Refer the constraint table now.
I am confused as to how equation of nutrient A will be.

Will it be,

> $$2x_1 + 3x_2 + 7x_3 \ge 750$$

or

> $$\frac{2}{8.5}x_1 + \frac{3}{7.5}x_2 + \frac{7}{8}x_3 \ge 750$$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for you mathematical expressions.

Comment: @AlainRemillard thanks for the suggestion. I have made necessary changes. I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: What is your work on the subject ? Met the farmer ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I just came across this problem. I understand that this is not a platform to complete homework. And it is not my intention. I am just looking for some guidance here.

Comment: @JeanMarie I am not looking for solution. Just stuck with LPP formulation.

Comment: It is the first inequation (but why 750 ? It should be 950.). Explanation : $A$ "works for itself", it is not its concern if such and such feed contains few or many B,C,D Nutrients...